# Get variable in S Function from Workspace

Tags: matlab, simulink, workspace, s-function

I would like to get variable in S-Function (.cpp and wrapper.cpp) from workspace of Matlab.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call into MATLAB from an S-Function using mexCallMATLAB function. Using mexCallMATLAB you can call any MATLAB function from S-Function. Combining this with evalin function you can get a variable from base workspace. The syntax for calling mexCallMATLAB is

```
int mexCallMATLAB(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,
  mxArray *prhs[], const char *functionName);
```

You should set your functionName to "evalin" and the first argument in prhs to be the string "base", and the second argument to be the name of the variable.

Having said that, the recommended way to get a variable into s-function is through parameters. You should add a parameter to s-function and then you can specify your variable as the parameter value. This parameter can be accessed from the s-function using standard s-function API functions like ssGetSFcnParam. See example s-functions mentioned in the doc at https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/ssgetsfcnparam.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example:

```
double Tinit;
mxArray* args[2];
args[0] = mxCreateString("base");
args[1] = mxCreateString("Tinit");
mxArray* out;
mexCallMATLAB(1, &out, 2, args, "evalin"); //eval in workspace base
Tinit = *mxGetPr(out);   //gets the double result
```

You should only use values from workspace when they have a true global meaning. 
In my example it is the value of a special step time period, which should not provide with an extra parameter.